# Why wait() funtion ( system call ) never return ( make an infinity wait)

Tags: c, operating-system

I want to simulate the pipe command : ls | sort | wc -l by writing some code but I comfront a strange problem  ( I can solve it by remove the line but I don't know the reason why it is an error)
When I remove the last wait command it run exactly and finish. But when I add this, it will wait  infinity .

```
int main()
{
        
    int pfds[2];

    int pfds1[2];

    pipe(pfds);     // create a pipe

    pid_t pid = fork();   // create child proess
      
    if (pid == 0)           // child process
    {
        dup2(pfds[1],1);     // change the stdout to pipe
        close(pfds[0]);
        execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);    // run the ls command
    }
    else {                   //  main process
        wait(0);           // wait for the child process
        pipe(pfds1);          //  make a pipe
        pid_t npid = fork();     // create child process

        if (npid == 0)              // child process
        {
            dup2(pfds[0],0);             // change the stdin to pipe
            close(pfds[1]); 
            dup2(pfds1[1], 1);              // get data from pipe
            close(pfds1[0]);
            execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);     // run sort command ( combine with above is ls | sort )
        }
        else {       // main process
            wait(0);             // this line will make infinity wait 
            dup2(pfds[0], 0);                      
            close(pfds[1]); 
            execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);              // run wc -l command 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're on Linux, you can [run your application under `strace`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and and see where the processes get hung up.  Something like `strace -f -o /path/to/output/file ./yourApp`.  You'll see the actual system calls your processes all make, and you can see which system call if any a process gets hung in.  As @ikegami noted, you probably have a deadlock - your parent process is waiting for the child process to end, but the child process is blocked writing to its pipe, which is backed up because the parent process isn't reading from it.

Comment: For what it's worth, you're not the first programmer who has run into that type of deadlock when running multiple processes, and you won't be the last.  I'd be most programmers who are aware of the finite capacity of pipes learned about it by running into this very deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't closing fds you should be closing. Remember that a file handle is only closed once all file descriptors to it are closed. For example, if you're not careful, it's possible for `ls` to have completed but `sort` not realizing this because of a missing `close`.

Also, your code is susceptible to deadlocks. If `ls` were to output a large amount, it would write to the first pipe until it's full and block. The parent, rather than emptying the pipe, is waiting for the child to end. Deadlock.

Make sure to close fds you don't need anymore, and start every children before waiting for any to end.

```c
int pfds1[2]; pipe(pfds1);

pid_t pid1 = fork();
if (!pid1) {
   close(pfds1[0]);
   dup2(pfds1[1], 1); close(pfds1[1]);
   execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
}

close(pfds1[1]);

int pfds2[2]; pipe(pfds2);

pid_t pid2 = fork();
if (!pid2) {
   close(pfds2[0]);
   dup2(pfds1[0], 0); close(pfds1[0]);
   dup2(pfds2[1], 1); close(pfds2[1]);
   execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);
}

close(pfds2[1]);

pid_t pid3 = fork();
if (!pid3) {
   dup2(pfds2[0], 0); close(pfds2[0]);
   execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
}

waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);
waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0);
waitpid(pid3, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I am a newbie in system programing so I am quite not understand some concept.